# Discord.py only one slash command showing

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm extremely new to the discord.py module, and I am having troubles getting multiple slash commands set up at once. I have tried looking for solution but to no avail, only seeing that I need to sync.

My code:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
import os
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='for furries'))
    


@tree.command(name = "testing", description = "The Description", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id_here))
async def first_command(interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_message("Hello! V2")

@tree.command(name = "ping", description = "Ping Pong", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id_here))
async def second_command(interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_message("Pong!")


try:
    client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
except discord.HTTPException as e:
    if e.status == 429:
        print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
    else:
        raise e
```

It only shows testing command, and even if I rearrange the code, it only shows testing.

Answer (score 0):

i used some code from my bot

here is the working code:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import os

TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']

class aclient(discord.Client):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())
    self.synced = False

  async def on_ready(self):
    await self.wait_until_ready()
    if not self.synced:
      await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id = guild_id_here))
      self.synced = True
    print(f'We have logged in as {self.user}.')

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=discord.Intents.default())

@tree.command(name = "testing", description = "The Description", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id_here))
async def first_command(interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_message("Hello! V2")

@tree.command(name = "ping", description = "Ping Pong", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id_here))
async def second_command(interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_message("Pong!")



try:
    client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
except discord.HTTPException as e:
    if e.status == 429:
        print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
    else:
        raise e
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you, and I figured out why it hadn't worked before using your code, thanks so much!